# ng-src and ng-error in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of images which I take from my localhost. I want to show images until its finished in array. If there is no a directory then the image should not be shown in the slider.

```html
 <ngb-carousel>
     <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let photo of navbar.infoData.attributes.photo">
          <img class="card-img-top img-fluid w-full" [ng-src]="photo" (err=src)="some links" alt="Okul Fotoğrafı Bulunamadı">
     </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Comment: Its just `[src]` without `ng`

Comment: That is not the problem but thanks :)

Comment: As Faisal said, you should use [src]. If it does not work, maybe your path is invalid. Did you try to display `{{ photo  }}` above the `img` tag just to see what contains `photo`?

Comment: [src] works of course but my case is different. I want to show images in the slider but when it can not find the image in directory it should show a simple image. I want to use ng-src and ng-error.